# Kendo UI: How to swap DOM elements by Remove/Add

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

https://jsbin.com/jigefipiye/edit?html,console,output

I have 2 templates one used visible and invisible binding and one uses # if () #

```
 <div>Template 1</div>
  <div id="to-bind1" data-bind="source: Data" data-template="template1"></div>

  <div>Template 2</div>
  <div id="to-bind2" data-bind="source: Data" data-template="template2"></div>

  <script id="template1" type="x"> 
    <li>
      # if (Readonly) { #
          <span data-bind="text: Val"></span>
      # } else { #
          <input data-bind="value: Val" />
      # } #
    </li>
  </script>


  <script id="template2" type="x"> 
    <li>
      <span data-bind="visible: Readonly, text: Val"></span>
      <input data-bind="invisible: Readonly, value: Val" />
    </li>
  </script>


  <script>
    var toBind1 = $("#to-bind1");
    var toBind2 = $("#to-bind2");

    var vm = kendo.observable({
      Data: [{
        Readonly: true,
        Val: "Woot!"  
      }],
    });

    kendo.bind(toBind1, vm);
    kendo.bind(toBind2, vm);

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('dfs')
      vm.get('Data')[0].set('Readonly', false);
    }, 5000)
  </script>
```

after 5 seconds the Template2 swap to an input box and Template1 remain the same

[image]

the problem is that in template2 the input is hidden 
what i want to achieve is swap the input with span and vise versa instead of hiding it

somethings similar to the if binding in knockoutJS https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

> if (and ifnot) play a similar role to the visible (and hidden)
>   bindings. The difference is that, with visible, the contained markup
>   always remains in the DOM and always has its data-bind attributes
>   applied—the visible binding just uses CSS to toggle the container
>   element’s visiblity. The if binding, however, physically adds or
>   removes the contained markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to
>   descendants if the expression is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/lavunidapo/edit?html,console,output

This shows what you want I think you are wanting to achieve (maybe). It changes Readonly from the initial state and re-renders both item templates. But to do so we have to take the object out of the array and re-push it into the array so that the item template re-renders again.  It will then run the JS portion which looks something like this:

```js
var $kendoOutput, 
    $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;
with(data) { 
    $kendoOutput=' \n <li>\n '; 
    if (Readonly) {
        ;$kendoOutput+='\n <span data-bind="text: Val"></span>\n '; 
    } else { 
        ;$kendoOutput+='\n <input data-bind="value: Val" />\n ';
    } ;
    $kendoOutput+='\n </li>\n ';
}
return $kendoOutput;
```

After the LI is rendered with the above code then the bindings are setup. Bindings will re-evaluate if the field bound to changes. But things that change do not re-render the template (i.e. it doesn't run the above JS again) you have to replace the whole item to have the script above to re-run.

Comment: Thanks @jwwishart.cv you're solution worked, I just need to splice the data and reinsert for the template to get re-rendered.